# Elastic IP not pingable with AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-ip

After instantiating a micro server I created an elastic IP and associated my micro instance with it. In my micro instance settings panel in AWS, I see "Public IP" address and an "Elastic IP" address, which as far as I can understand, means the association was successful. However, I am able to ping the Public IP but not the Elastic IP. Am I missing a step here

[image: IPs]

Answer (score 1):

Check the Security Profile for your instance and to make sure you've allowed echo requests (AKA ping) to come thru.  Basic settings for such a rule would be:

Type: Custom ICMP Rule
Protocol: ICMP Request
Port Range: N/A
Source: (whatever IPs you want to allow pings from)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Brandon. But how is it possible that I can ping the Public IP but not the Elastic one? Don't they share the same Security settings?

Comment: I'm a little surprised your public and elastic ips don't match for a basic setup.  The "public" one is actually a DHCP (or other similar mechanism) assigned one from a pool that will almost certainly change with every reboot of your server.  The elastic one is relatively static and should be the one you reference.  Are you CERTAIN they aren't the same?  It's possible you are pinging the next guy's server who happened to receive your previous public IP.

Comment: I edited the post with a screenshot from AWS